# Idenitity UserManager ConfirmEmailAsync not implementing IUserEmailStore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

MVC application using AspNet.Identity

I've set my application up so when someone registers an account they are sent a verification email with a token to confirm the account.

I have had this working previously in a different application so am not sure why this isn't working.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
try
        {
            var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("SOMETHING");
            UserManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(provider.Create("EmailConfirmation"));
            result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);
        }
```

Now when i breakpoint my code, it is giving me the error when i get to ConfirmEmailAsync, i am passing ina userId and Code, but for some reason it is wanting me to implement IUserEmailStore.

I haven't had to do this previously, and the above code has worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue. It was because my Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework was on version 1.

Its partly(read all) my fault as I assumed when I updated the identity it would update all of the identity references, apparently not.